# Автоклик по элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

При загрузке документа происходит клик по элементу с классом `clearsearchclass` с задержкой в 400мс:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 setTimeout('document.getElementsByClassName("clearsearchclass")[0].click()', 400);
});
```

Если убрать `setTimeout`, то клик не происходит. Как мне моментально сделать клик?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.clearsearchclass').first().click(); //Для первого элемента как в примере
});
```

Для плагина jqrid (Из комментариев)

```
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid({
...
   gridComplete: function(id){ 
      $('.clearsearchclass').first().click(); 
   },
...
});
```

Название события взято из документации плагина http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

Comment: Но клик почему-то не происходит. Работает, только если задержку добавляю

Comment: Попробуйте заменить первую строку на $( window ).load(function() {

Comment: не исправило ситуацию

Comment: В консоль никаких ошибок не выводит? Элемент уже существует на момент загрузки страницы?

Comment: похоже, что все таки после загрузки страницы. да и в консоли ошибка, что элемента не существует

Comment: Можно полный jquery/html код? Добавьте его в текст вопроса.

Comment: это плагин jqgrid, формирует таблицу аяксом. Код нету смысла кидать тк он не очевиден. но все-таки таблица формируется после загрузки страницы

Comment: Тогда имитатор клика повесьте на событие gridComplete. Добавил в текст ответа примерный код

Comment: Хороший вариант, по идее должен работать, но нет

Comment: Что теперь пишет в консоли?

Comment: ничего не пишет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45038/discussion-between---and-evgenii-zaets).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $('.clearsearchclass').trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Я это уже предложил. У автора в другом суть проблемы.

Comment: да, увидел... но смысл не меняется load можно вызывать на таблицу.. https://api.jquery.com/load-event/